# Functional analysis - Hilbert space - Existence of subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud4iJ.png)

Hello, i have this exercise where i need to show for a separable Hilbert space there exist some subsequence with a special property. But im stuck even at the beginning, so i hope someone can help me atleast some idea of where to start.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you could just spell the exercise out instead of posting a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every Hilbert space is reflexive it follows from Kakutani's Theorem.